# Move the files from two machines into four machines in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scp

I am working on a project in which I need to move the files from one machine to another machine. All the machines are Ubuntu machine and it is running Ubuntu 12.04. So I guess, I can scp the files directly.

Now below is my text file which will get generated by another program with details about which machine has which files.

```
{ dbx45.dc1.host.com=[0, 1024, 4, 1028],
  dbx46.dc1.host.com=[1, 1025, 5, 1029],
  dbx47.dc1.host.com=[2, 1026, 6, 1030],
  dbx48.dc1.host.com=[3, 1027, 7, 1031] }
```

In the above text file, I have a set of `key = value` pair combinations, where `key is the client machine name` and `value is the name of files` each machine is responsible for. For example in the above file,

```
dbx45.dc1.host.com is the client machine responsible for 0 file name, 1024 file name, 4 file name, 1028 file name.
dbx46.dc1.host.com is the client machine responsible for 1 file name, 1025 file name, 5 file name, 1029 file name.
dbx47.dc1.host.com is the client machine responsible for 2 file name, 1026 file name, 6 file name, 1030 file name.
dbx48.dc1.host.com is the client machine responsible for 3 file name, 1027 file name, 7 file name, 1031 file name.
```

Now all the files are residing in these two machines only as mentioned below. Which means, files are distributed in these two below machines randomly so it is not like that only one machine contains all the files.

```
slc4b03.dc1.host.com
chd1b02.dc2.host.com
```

All the files in the above two machines resides in this folder -

`/bat/data/snapshot/`

and the file name is like this as an example -

```
`t1_weekly_0_200003_5.data` (this is for file 0)
`t1_weekly_1024_200003_5.data` (this is for file number 1024)
`t1_weekly_4_200003_5.data` (this is for file number 4)

and similarly for others as well.
```

Now the problem is to

1. Read the txt file and figure out which client machine is responsible for which files.
2. And then accordingly pull those files from those two machines (if it is not there in one machine, then it will be there in second machine) and put (scp) it in respective client machines in this path `(/export/home/username/primary)`.

I can run this shell script from any of the machines I guess as we are just scp(-ing) it.

I am not sure how we can do this in shell script? Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:-**

File Number is within file names.

This file - `t1_weekly_0_200003_5.data` is for file 0. Similarly, this file is -  `t1_weekly_1024_200003_5.data` is for file 1024.

Comment: not an answer, because it's not bash, but you definitely need to investigate fabric - http://docs.fabfile.org/ it's perfect for this use case.

Comment: @cforbish: I am able to read the files but not sure how to store these values in a datastructure and then accordingly pull the files from those two machines.

Comment: Looks simple enough. What's the format of the file that shows the relationship between filenames and filenumbers? I mean the file that tells you t1_weeklyxyz is file 0?

Comment: @MarkSetchell. As an example this file name is `t1_weekly_0_200003_5.data` is for file 0 as I mentioned in my question. And this file name is `t1_weekly_1024_200003_5.data` is for file number 1024. File Number is within File Names.

Comment: When do the codes `t1_weekly`, and `200003` and `5` change? Never? Is the data format in the file generated by another program recognized by Python?  It isn't quite a Perl format, though it is close.  Or maybe there's another language that the people who set this scheme up used that makes it easy to parse the control data (which file is mastered on which machine). If there is such a language, it is probably worth using it. Is the size of the lists of files fixed a 4 per machine, or can it vary, and is the number uniform across machines or does that vary, too? What about the number of machines?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler never.. Size can vary, it's not 4 per machine. It can be much larger. Number of machines can vary too as well.. The program that will be generating that machine mapping will be Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: the data structure can be read into Perl with minor modifications (that Perl is quite capable of handling).  This code takes the data file shown and converts it into a structure that this code prints:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Slurp input into $data
my $data;
{
local $/;
$data = <>;
}
print "data = <<$data>>\n";

# Convert to eval-able format
$data =~ s/{/ \$x = {/m;
$data =~ s/}/};/m;
$data =~ s/([^ ]+)=/"$1" => /gm;
print "data = <<$data>>\n";

# Eval it
my $x;
eval $data;

# Dump the data structure
foreach my $key (keys %{$x})
{
    foreach my $val (@{$x->{$key}})
    {
        print "$key: $val\n";
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
data = <<{ dbx45.dc1.host.com=[0, 1024, 4, 1028],
  dbx46.dc1.host.com=[1, 1025, 5, 1029],
  dbx47.dc1.host.com=[2, 1026, 6, 1030],
  dbx48.dc1.host.com=[3, 1027, 7, 1031] }
>>
data = << $x = { "dbx45.dc1.host.com" => [0, 1024, 4, 1028],
  "dbx46.dc1.host.com" => [1, 1025, 5, 1029],
  "dbx47.dc1.host.com" => [2, 1026, 6, 1030],
  "dbx48.dc1.host.com" => [3, 1027, 7, 1031] };
>>
dbx46.dc1.host.com: 1
dbx46.dc1.host.com: 1025
dbx46.dc1.host.com: 5
dbx46.dc1.host.com: 1029
dbx47.dc1.host.com: 2
dbx47.dc1.host.com: 1026
dbx47.dc1.host.com: 6
dbx47.dc1.host.com: 1030
dbx48.dc1.host.com: 3
dbx48.dc1.host.com: 1027
dbx48.dc1.host.com: 7
dbx48.dc1.host.com: 1031
dbx45.dc1.host.com: 0
dbx45.dc1.host.com: 1024
dbx45.dc1.host.com: 4
dbx45.dc1.host.com: 1028
```

What you do with the data from there needs to be considered, but at least you have a structure from which you can determine which files are held on a given machine.  You can easily create the inverted index listing which machine each file is held on.

You could (and probably should) add some data validation before modifying and evaluating the data, to minimize the chances of a malicious user feeding something dangerous into the data file.  (Many a program that reads executable code (think macros in some office products) from disk is vulnerable to being tricked by malicious code. Don't let your program be one of them!